# OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit not registering in Unity 5.3.4

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an inventory system and at the moment I am looking into swapping inventory spots. Currently I have a hierarchy as :

[image]

Now what I have noticed is when I am swapping it only works if I was to swap say for example Inventory Slot 1 with Inventory Slot 4.  BUT if I am to swap it back for example Inventory Slot 4 with Inventory Slot 1 my OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit do not register, is this supposed to be right?  This seems to be a hierarchy issue and I don't know how to solve this.

GIF of the swapping and a screenshot of my Inventory Slot GameObject :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZdqW.jpg - GIF

[image]

Code of my OnPointers for Inventory_Slot script :

```
public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
public static GameObject itemCurrentlyOn;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data){
    itemCurrentlyOn = gameObject;
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data){
    itemCurrentlyOn = null;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data){
    // IF we are dragging an item.
    if(itemBeingDragged != null){
        print (itemCurrentlyOn);
        // IF we release the mouse button on an actual inventory slot.
        if(itemCurrentlyOn != null && itemCurrentlyOn != gameObject){
            // Swap the information in the 2 inventory slots.
            GetComponentInParent<Inventory> ().SwapInventorySlots (itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<Inventory_Slot> (), itemCurrentlyOn.GetComponent<Inventory_Slot> ());
        }

        itemBeingDragged = null;
        // return this gameobject to its original location.
        rectTrans.localPosition = localRectTrans;
    }
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data){
    // IF we have an item to drag.
    if(isItem){
        // Set the itemBeingDragged to this gameobject.
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        // Set the current item we are hovered on to null.
        //itemCurrentlyOn = null;
    }
}
```

Also if I was to take Inventory Slot 5 and move it above Inventory Slot 1 in the hierarchy I can then do swapping backwards if that makes sense.  I'll post a GIF to make a better visual :

New Hierarchy :

[image]

[http://imgur.com/rjueuYK](https://imgur.com/rjueuYK) - GIF

Is how I am doing my inventory bad practice or is there something in Unity that I can slap on to one of my gameobjects to fix this hierarchy issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error might be caused because you may not be emptying the original slot where the item was in. This may not be the exact answer that you are looking for but in this tutorial a similar issue to the one you are facing is explain.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gveNfidKPA&t=17m5s

Hope this helps.